# Tensorflow: How to perform binary classification as pre-processing and perform linear regression training

Tags: tensorflow, classification, linear-regression

In Tensorflow, you can either perform either classification or linear regression to train your inputs against the labels. Is it possible to perform some classification for your inputs (as pre-processing but not necessarily to use Tensorflow) and determine if you want to run the linear regression using Tensorflow?

For example in image denoising task, you have found that your linear regression algorithm can provide a good smoothing effect against the edges but in the meantime also remove the details for the texture objects. Therefore you would like to perform a binary classification to determine if an input is a texture object, and run the linear regression algorithm using Tensorflow; otherwise do nothing for texture object.

I understand Tensorflow supports [transfer learning](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/image_retraining) so I guess one of the possible solutions is to perform binary classification using Tensorflow, and transfer the "texture classification" knowledge to instruct Tensorflow to apply linear regression algorithm only when the input is a texture object? Please correct me if I am wrong as I am not too sure if the above task is do-able in Tensorflow (it would be great if you can describe how to do this in details if this is do-able :-) ).

I guess an alternative solution is to use some binary classification without Tensorflow, and filter out (remove) the texture inputs before passing them to Tensorflow.

Please kindly tell me if which of the above solution (or any other solution) is better (if do-able) for the above scenario? Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: As far as I understand, you wanna: 1. do binary classification first; 2. gather the data with positive predictions and do regression.  `tf.boolean_mask` is perhaps what you are looking for.

Comment: @Richard_wth How should I use `tf.boolean_mask`? Is that I should filter out the texture like this `filtered_inputs = tf.boolean_mask(inputs, is_texture(inputs))` and pass `filtered_inputs` to `session.run`?

Comment: Yes, try that and see if there is any error. If not, you could pass `filtered_input` to the regression model. However, you may need to consider the chance that filtered_input is None (all inputs are from negative class).